# Is there any way to know if AUTO VERIFICATION failed in firebase phone authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

Firebase phone authentication is awesome. I understood that it has auto verification process which sometimes do not need to send otp. But is there any way to know if AUTO VERIFICATION has failed and only then prompt user to enter OTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                   if(notAutoRetrieval) {

                        //firebase send otp to the given phone number

                    }else{
                        //firebase does send otp to the given phone number
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                    // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                    // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                    // by combining the code with a verification ID.

                   // if firebase send otp this method is execute 


                    notAutoRetrieval=true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                    // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                    // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.

                    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // Invalid request
                        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this,e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                        // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }                      


                }
            });
```

please see this code. may be it helps you.